# getline() function is skipping inputs

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I have the following code that does some tests on nomC and nomP, but using 2 successive getlines causes skipping the the first one (getline(cin,nomP); ) .. how can i fix the problem ? PS : i tried cin.ignore(); and cin.clear(); and it didn't work

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    vector<string> decision(T);
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
         string nomP,nomC;
        string help="";
        vector<string> desc;
        bool accepted = true;
        getline(cin,nomP);
        getline(cin,nomC);
        while(help!="----")
        { getline(cin,help); desc.push_back(help);}
        if ((nomP.size()<5)|| (nomP.size()>20))
          {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 1.\n";accepted=false;}
        if (nomP[0]<65|| nomP[0]>90)
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 2.\n";accepted=false;}
        if (nomP[nomP.size()]==32)
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 3.\n";accepted=false;}
        if((nomC.size()<5)|| (nomC.size()>10))
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 4.\n";accepted=false;}
        for(int j=0;j<nomC.size();j++)
        {
            if(((nomC[j]<48)&&(nomC[j]>57))||((nomC[j]<97)&&(nomC[j]>122)))
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 5.\n";accepted=false;break;}
        }
        if (desc.size()>10)
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 6.\n";accepted=false;}
        for(int j=0;j<desc.size();j++)
        {
            if((desc[j].size()<1)||(desc[j].size()>80))
            {decision[i] = nomC+" rejected with error code 7.\n";accepted=false;break;}
        }
        if (accepted)
            decision[i] = nomC+" is OK.\n";
    }
    for (int i=0;i<decision.size();i++)
    {
        cout<< decision[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are trying to read the same line into two different variables? Each call to getline() reads a line from cin, so you should only make one call and then copy nomP to nomC.

Comment: but i want nomP and nomC as seperated variables.. they should contain different strings .. any ideas about how to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at  your program this way

```
int T;
cin >> T;
```

> Console input: 5\n

You may have noticed the problem already. You think what you get is a 5, but its a 5 + a line break.

> Console input: Name\n

Then you call getline()

> cin buffer is not: Name\n,
>
> it's actually: \nName\n

Therefore, with the first getline you are reading a single "\n"

and with the second one, you are finally reading "Name\n"

There's ways to approach this issue. One is doing this trick

```
    while (isspace(cin.peek())) cin.ignore(); //dodge spaces, line breaks. 
    getline(cin, nomP);
    getline(cin, nomC);
```

I only use windows, but maybe the line breaks could be \r\n in another OS, that's why doing a single cin.ignore() may not be enough. So the trick still works.

But there's a better way: make a function, which returns only when it has read a non empty line. Something like:

```
string my_getline()
{
    string result;

    while (!getline(cin, result) || result.empty());

    return result;
}

string nomP = my_getline();
string nomC = my_getline();
```

With RVO this is as fast as doing getline(cin,nomP), and more simple.

Comment: @OmArElGhati No problem, maybe accept my answer as correct then? :D

Comment: It's not exactly true that it's as fast as getline, though I appreciate the sentiment. In a situation where you call this function repeatedly, it will allocate memory on every single call. Heap allocations are pretty slow. Whereas getline reuses the buffer, so it only allocates when a line is larger than all previous. On non pathological input getline will be much faster.

Comment: He's wiping both strings in every loop (therefore deallocating the memory), and he's also using both strings at the same time. How can getline reuse a buffer thats being used?. For his program it's as fast. For other cases, where you actually need such optimization, of course you can move the strings out of the loop, and call my_getline with a reference. Sure. But for simple tasks, keeping things simple and readable is better imo.

Comment: @OmArElGhati It's a bit sad that the wrong answer is accepted as the right one. Did you know that you can send multiple lines as console input, and doing a cin.ignore(2459259234) like he does, will make your code break in such cases?. Yes, he may have pointed out more issues that you initially had, but you only asked about a very specific problem, and I  gave you the correct answer, while he didn't. In the future, people will end up here from google or some other place and will end up getting the wrong answer. But whatever.

Comment: If he's attempting to input his loop integer on its own line, and doesn't want to input any other lines along with it, which appears to be the case from his program, then clearing out the buffer after won't break anything.  I wrote my answer with that in mind.  Your solution is for inputting data in general, mine is specifically for `getline()` returning a newline and nothing else after reading data from `cin`.

Comment: Again, my answer is aimed specifically at the problem at hand, and at what appears to be going wrong on his end.  Based on his question, he's entering data on multiple lines, not cramming it all into a single line.  I've tried it on Windows console and an online compiler running GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu), and it works properly when used in the manner his question implies that he's using it.  And why do you think I'm going to edit my answer, just because you intentionally looked for ways to break it so he would accept your answer instead?

Comment: Looked for ways to break your code? I knew about this issue long time ago, so when I see a person recommend it... Is a bit odd, yeah. If I want to test a console program, and I dont wanna type 10 different inputs, I can just copy paste them. Thats what I've done all my life. With your program I can't do it, because it breaks. And people in the future will take your code, and make the same mistake. But whatever. He initially accepted my answer, but since you gave him more answers he didn't ask for, he changed it. I'm not cramming it all in a single line. It's a simple copy paste of multiple lin

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that after you get the number of iterations from `cin`, you aren't clearing the newline character out.  So, when you call `getline()` for the first time, it merrily just grabs everything up to that newline you inadvertently left there, instead of getting a separate line.

Try entering the following input, and you'll see what I mean:

```
2 Fred
Ted
----
Bob
Joel
----
```

Try this instead:

```
#include <limits>

// ...

int T;
cin >> T;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This should clear out anything left on the line after inputting your loop size.

---

I would also like to suggest adding prompts to the program, at least during troubleshooting.  It's easier to see what's happening that way.

```
std::cout << "Input number of iterations: ";
cin >> T;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

// ...

std::cout << "Input first name: ";
getline(cin,nomP);
std::cout << "Input second name: ";
getline(cin,nomC);

while(help!="----")
{
    std::cout << "Input separator: ";
    getline(cin,help);
    desc.push_back(help);
}
```

---

Additionally, I'd like to point out two potential problems with your error code setup: The last error message encountered will overwrite any previous ones, and all of your error messages say the problem is in `nomC`, regardless of whether they're checking `nomP` or `nomC`.

```
// Issues pointed out with C-style comments.
if ((nomP.size()<5)|| (nomP.size()>20))
{
    /* Checks nomP, says error is in nomC. */
    decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 1.\n";
    accepted=false;
}
/* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites the
   previous error message.
 */
if (nomP[0]<65|| nomP[0]>90)
{
    /* Checks nomP, says error is in nomC. */
    decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 2.\n";
    accepted=false;
}
/* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites the
   previous error message.
 */
if (nomP[nomP.size()]==32)
{
    /* Checks nomP, says error is in nomC. */
    decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 3.\n";
    accepted=false;
}
/* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites the
   previous error message.
 */
if((nomC.size()<5)|| (nomC.size()>10))
{
    decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 4.\n";
    accepted=false;
}
for(int j=0;j<nomC.size();j++)
{
    /* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites
       the previous error message.
     */
    if(((nomC[j]<48) && (nomC[j]>57)) || ((nomC[j]<97) && (nomC[j]>122)))
    {
        decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 5.\n";
        accepted=false;
        break;
    }
}
/* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites the
   previous error message.
 */
if (desc.size()>10)
{
    /* Checks number of strings in desc, says error is in nomC. */
    decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 6.\n";
    accepted=false;
}
for(int j=0;j<desc.size();j++)
{
    /* If conditions are met for both this and the previous error message, this overwrites
       the previous error message.
     */
    if((desc[j].size()<1) || (desc[j].size()>80))
    {
        /* Checks string in desc, says error is in nomC. */
        decision[i] = nomC + " rejected with error code 7.\n";
        accepted=false;
        break;
    }
}
```

There are two ways to handle this:

1. If you're only concerned with one error message at a time, you can either leave it alone or change the `if` statements into `else if` ones.  (For the `if` statements in and after the `for` loops, you could add a condition that checks if there's already a string at `decision[i]`.)
2. If you want to get every error message, then use `decision.push_back()` instead of assigning directly to `decision[i]`.